# What's an adjective for "pertaining to donkeys"?

Tags: adjectives, animals

Horse is to Equine as Donkey is to ...?

Comment: Donkular.  (Just kidding...)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> [asinine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asinine) : *of, relating to, or resembling an ass*

(also *extremely or utterly foolish*), M-W.

In perspective:

*aquiline* - eagle
*asinine* - donkey
*bovine* - cattle
*cancrine* - crab
*canine* - dog
*cervine* - deer
*corvine* - crow
*equine* - horse
*elapine* - snake
*elaphine* - red deer
*feline* - cat
*hircine* - goat
*leonine* - lion
*leporine* - rabbit, hare
*lupine* - wolf
*murine* - rodent
*pavonine* - peacock
*piscine* - fish
*porcine* - pig
*rusine* - deer
*serpentine* - snake
*ursine* - bear
*vulpine* - fox

(source (edited): input by beatlesfanatic123456 to [this post](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080425173133AAPocQI))

Comment: Gosh, decisions, decisions!  Asinine or Equine? Both are correct, but yours is more specific to the species rather than the family, albeit a little more known for its "foolish" connotation.  As it happens, the double entendre fits very well in the sentence I'm trying to write, so you get credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, context is king, as they say. On a limited scale of occasions, I'd use _feline_ as _'pertaining to a lion'_; generally I'd go for a more specific word, if available to me.

Comment: This is a revelation, anemone, I'd never realized the extent of the -ine *suffix*?

Comment: What, no *anemonine*?

Comment: how come deer get three?

Comment: @jk _Oh deer_. I must not copy and paste other people's posts, must I?

Comment: For completeness sake, Ovine could be added too.

Comment: It would appear you can use *hemionine* or *hemionid* to mean like an onager, kulan or kiang - source: http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/tetrapod-zoology/fantastic-asses/ - I'm sure that would be very useful.

Comment: It should be noted that asinine usually carries a heavy negative connotation, as opposed to the generally neutral connotation of equine.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson That's true if you use it to refer to something (or someone) that isn't actually a donkey. If you used it in a zoological context, I don't think it would be a negative.

Comment: @abligh Thanks a lot. You just got me flagged at work for going to a site called "Fantastic Asses"

Comment: @Barmar I would argue that the "idiotic" definition is so much more commonly used than the "pertaining to a specific animal" definition that if you were to refer to an actual donkey as "asinine", it would take the average person at least a little while to realize that you didn't mean it was a particularly silly and/or brainless specimen of the species. If I didn't want to imply I meant both meanings, I would feel compelled just to create a new word via morphology, like "donkeyish".

Comment: @neminem Good point. It really depends on where the desired word will be used. If it's used with average people, it would indeed be misunderstood. If it were used in a scientific journal, where you were distinguishing horse-like and donkey-like traits, I think it would be safe.

Comment: @dberm22 - well, I guess someone just made a donkey of you. :-)

Answer (score 17):

As other answers have pointed out, *asinine* is an adjective relating to donkeys. In addition, donkeys are also *equine*. *Equine* means *relating to the horse family*, which happens to include donkeys as well as asses and zebras.

The  small contribution of this answer here is to provide a list of animals and corresponding animal adjectives with the *-ine* suffix. This has been partially gleaned from [this page at tinyonline.co.uk](http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/animalaj.htm). It's alphabetical, so you'll need to scroll to the animal you're interested in:

> **A**

**ant** formicine, myrmecine

**anteater**    myrmecophagine

**antelope**    antilopine

**armadillo**   tolypeutine

**ass** asinine

> **B**

**badger**  meline, musteline

**barracuda**   percesocine

**basilisk lizard** basilicine

**bat** noctilionine, pteropine

**bear**    ursine

**bird**    avine, volucrine

**bird of prey**    accipitrine

**bison**   bisontine

**bull**    taurine

**butterfly**   pieridine, pierine

**buzzard** cathartine, pyrrhuloxine

> **C**

**calf**    vituline

**camel**   cameline

**carp**    cyprine

**cat** feline

**chicken** galline

**coral**   coralline

**cormorant**   phalacrocoracine

**cow** bovine vaccine

**crab**    cancrine

**crocodile**   crocodiline

**crow**    corvine

**cuckoo**  cuculine

> D

**deer**    cervine

**dodo**    didine

**dog** canine

**dolphin** delphine

**domestic fowl**   galline

**dormouse**    myoxine

**dove**    columbine

**dragon**  draconine

> **E**

**eagle** aquiline

**earthworm**   lumbricine

**elephant**    elephantine

**ermine**  musteline

> F

**fish**    piscine

**flea**    pulicine

**fox** vulpine

**frog**    ranine

**fur seal**    otarine

> **G**

**gerbil**  cricetine

**giant ground sloth**  megatherine

**gibbon**  hylobatine

**giraffe** giraffine

> **H**

**hamster** cricetine

**hare**    leporine

**hawk**    accipitrine, falconine

**hippopotamus**    hippopotamine

**horse**   caballine, equine

**human**   hominine

**hummingbird** trochilidine, trochiline

**humpback whale**  megapterine

> **I**

**ibis**    ibidine

> **J**

**jay** garruline

> **K**

**kangaroo**    macropine, macropodine

**kea** nestorine

**kingfisher**  dacelonine, halcyonine

**kite**    milvine

> **L**

**lemming** microtine

**lemur**   lemurine

**leopard** pardine

**limpet**  patelline

**lion**    leonine

**lizard**  lacertine

**lobster** homarine

**louse**   pediculine

**lynx**    lyncine

> **M**

**macaw**   psittacine

**mamba**   elapine

**manatee** manatine

**mite**    acarine

**mockingbird** mimine

**mole**    talpine

**mongoose**    herpestine, viverrine

**moose**   cervine

**mosquito**    aedine, anopheline, culicine

**mouse**   murine, musine

**musk ox** ovibovine

> **N**

**nuthatch**    sittine

> **O**

**octopus** octopine

**opposum** didelphine

**oriole**  icterine

**ostrich** struthionine

**otter**   lutrine, musteline

**owl** strigine

**ox**  bovine, taurine

**oyster**  ostracine

> **P**

**panther** pantherine

**parrot**  psittacine

**partridge**   perdicine

**peacock** pavonine

**perch**   percine

**pheasant**    phasianine

**pig** porcine, suilline

**pigeon**  pullastrine

**polecat** musteline

**porcupine**   hystricine

**porpoise**    phocaenine

**python**  pythonine

> **Q**

**quail**   coturnine

> **R**

**rabbit**  leporine

**rat** murine

**rattlesnake** crotaline

**rhinoceros**  ceratorhine, rhinerocerine

**robin**   turdine

**rodent**  glirine

> **S**

**salamander**  salamandrine

**sea horse**   hippocampine

**sea lion**    otarine

**seal**    phocine

**serpent** serpentine

**sheep**   ovine

**shrew**   soricine

**silkworm**    bombycine

**skunk**   mephitine, musteline

**skylark** alaudine

**snake**   anguilline, anguine, colubrine, serpentine, viperine

**sparrow** emberizine, passerine

**sphinx**  sphingine, sphinxine

**squirrel**    sciurine

**starling**    sturnine

**swan**    cygnine

> **T**

**termite** termitine

**tick**    acarine

**tiger**   tigrine

**titmouse**    parine, penduline

**toad**    bufotenine

**tortoise**    testudine

**turkey**  meleagrine

> **V**

**viper**   viperine

**vole**    microtine

**vulture** cathartine, vulturine

> **W**

**walrus**  odobenine

**wasp**    vespine

**weasel**  musteline

**wolf**    lupine

**wren**    troglodytine

> **Z**

**zebra**   equine hippotigrine, zebrine

If you want to see a lot of other lists which have snaffled lots of info from various dictionaries, you could try any of these:

http://www.dnafrequencies.com/dp/terms.shtml

http://www.davekoelle.com/animal_terms.html

https://elisabethaskin.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/27/

http://www273.pair.com/med/words/animal_adjectives.htm

http://www.dnafrequencies.com/dp/terms.shtml

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why we need to see the adjective for wasps and warblers, etc., when the OP asked about donkeys? :-/

Comment: @KristinaLopez Yes, it's slightly off-topic, but hopefully interestingly tangentially related.

Comment: Definitely interesting! :-)

Comment: Where does "simian" fit in?  It doesn't end in "-ine"... what's the difference?

Comment: @ShaulBehr *Simian* comes from the Latin for *ape*, "simia". In modern biology it refers to both apes and monkeys, namely animals or the infraborder *Simiiformes*. It ends in 'n' but this is just derivation from the Latin *simia* it does not have the Latin suffix *-inus*, meaning *like*, which is where the other English adjectives ending in *-ine* get the modern suffix from :)

Comment: Your verb "crimped" should actually be "cribbed". Crimp means to make something ruffled. Crib, as a verb, has several meanings, one of which is to copy sth. dishonestly. I read once it came from Cambridge University student slang, but cannot find a reference for such an etymology at the moment.

Comment: I think there's a policy against copying and pasting **entire** pieces of content like this. It's recommended instead to copy a **relevant sample** (e.g. trim it down to the 'A' section which contains 'Ass', or a selection of equine animals). That would be "fair use", while this could be copying/plagirism which might be illegal depending on that site's copyright and might be penalised by search engines as duplicate content.

Comment: I was hoping that the adjective form of _ermine_ would be _erminine_.

Comment: Can one claim it is fully productive then?

Comment: @user568458 Well, it's now a partial list. But I can't copyright a list of all the letters in the alphabet even if I put it on my website. That list is just a compilation like thousands of others on the web (one identical one, probably the original of this reverse-engineered one, now included in the post)  that just regurgitates info that's well-known and in the public domain without any comment, translation or personal input. But if I'm wrong about that I'll happily delete this list

Answer (score 5):

The donkey [(*equus africanus asinus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey) is one of the [*Equidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey) (horses), which are in the order [*Perissodactyla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate) (odd-toed ungulates) which are, yes, [*Ungulates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungulate)  (hoofed), and the ungulates are *Mammals*. as people have said. So donkeys are in all of these groups, and we could refer to them indirectly by using the name of any one.

But there is only one term to use for donkeys exclusively, and that is their own: **asinine.** (+1 to anemone).

(Also, if we give the answer "equine", the OP's comparison becomes "**Horse** is to **Equine** as **Donkey** is to **Equine.** Don't work, really, do it?)

Answer (score 1):

```
I had a Donkey, that was all right,
But he always wanted to fly my Kite;
Every time I let him, the String would bust.
Your Donkey is better behaved, I trust.
```

A problem with other answers here is that many donkeys are not a bit asinine. In modern English usage, the application of that word to 'personages with long ears' has been overwhelmed by its application to unpleasant humans. So, depending on the particular writing problem you are trying to solve, you may prefer some more complex expression. Descriptive words like 'stubborn,' 'braying', or 'unaccountably handsome' might serve.

Comment: Actually I was writing an essay involving an actual donkey, and I wanted some synonyms to relieve the overuse of the word "donkey".  So "asinine" was perfect, especially coming as it did in the context of some really stupid behavior.

Comment: So, should we eschew perfectly good English usage because a word has more than one meaning? Do we allow people to choose from a variety of meanings using knowledge, resources and more importantly, context? Or do we insist that every word should have an unambiguous single meaning?

Comment: @Margana are you trying to be clear? My claim is that, in common usage, asinine has travelled well past 'ambiguous'. If you write asinine, no reader is going to think about furry ears. In any case, I wrote, 'you may prefer.'  _You_ may prefer not.

Comment: @bmargulies: sorry. I wasn't really aiming my comment at your specific answer, which I think works ok. I was trying to query a more general point about whether we always need to go with the most obvious choices, regardless of context. I'd have had no trouble identifying the meaning of asinine if I was reading about donkeys, I think.

Comment: Before today I didn't even associate asinine with actual donkeys, and would have credited OP with a clever pun when I read it

Comment: @Margana fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

A donkey in an ***[equine](http://www.fao.org/docrep/t0690e/t0690e07.htm)***:

Equine animals:

> - Equines are the members of the horse family and have single hoofed feet. ***The equines are the horse, donkey, mule and hinny.*** The father of the hinny is a horse and the mother is a donkey.

(www.fao.org)

Answer (score 0):

**Equine** is more of a scientific-rooted word, which effectively means that Horses are Equine because they belong to the genus **Equus**, and so do the Donkeys. But, still, Equine is a specific word used **just** for horses. One can use **Assinine** for Donkeys though.

Comment: I don't think anyone uses ***assine***. Is that a typo for ***asinine**?*